# Routing table - Routes with heading

Tags: routing

I want to know when routes headings are added ?

For example:
[image]

Are they added only for directly connected routes?

Comment: With 'heading' you mean destination network = prefix?

Comment: the networks that have headers , the one with red box in the routing table in the image , i want to know why it only shows the classful network information for these subnets only ?

Comment: That is _not_ classful information. The `10.0.0.0`, `11.0.0.0`, and `12.0.0.0` as [deprecated] classful networks would be Class A with a `/8` mask, but those are in the routing table with a `/24` mask

Comment: @sam Those are no headers but prefixes. Also, classful networking is long dead. It died in 1993 with the introduction of CIDR. Please leave it dead and buried.

Comment: @RonMaupin thanks for the clarification , so for any network , if the router finds that it uses a class less mask it will show the same info right ?  and that's the case for 10,11,12 subnets with /24 . I'm asking because i heard that if the router knows if there is 2 subnets for the same classful network it will show this heading, so i thought the 2nd one for each of the first three is the local route , but not showing here because the IOS version  < 15 .

Comment: @Zac67 Ok RIP classful

Comment: @sam Non-ancient devices may use former classes for default prefix lengths, but none of them is using classful networking any more. Please just forget everything about classes as it seems to confuse you. Also, the prefix lengths themselves don't matter for anything but defining the current prefix length. It's the prefixes that matter.